# Testing FTP Output of a Stream

Tags: c#, excel, console

Brand new to StackOverflow.... I'm writing a console app in C#. I'd like to verify that an Excel spreadsheet is streaming correctly using FTP.

The application calls a stored procedure, populates a datatable with the result set, reads the datatable into a stream and then FTP's that stream onto a 3rd party site. I'd like to upload the stream somewhere besides that actual 3rd party site just to verify everything shows properly on the other end. Looking for help with how to do that.

I've tried setting up a local FTP but received the following error when trying to create the FTPWebRequest:

"The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command."

```
        FtpWebRequest myWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp address");
```

I also tried Console.Out with no luck.

This is what my code to upload looks like:

```
 StreamReader sourceStream;

        using (sourceStream = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());

        }


        myWebRequest.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;




        using (Stream requestStream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        }

        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Upload File Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");
        }
```

Comment: Assuming `path` contains the path to the Excel file you mentioned, you definitely don't want to interpret that as UTF-8. It could have byte sequences that are invalid *characters* and you would be corrupting the file. Use `fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(path);` instead. Fixing that could obviate this verification step entirely.

Comment: Is "ftp address" the actual address you use or is it a replacement to hide the real address. Could help to know the real value

Comment: Also you need to set the method of the request => `myWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;`

Comment: @Kalten, thanks for your help. Yes it's to hide the real address and the method was defined higher up in the code (not included in my snippet). The format of the address is ftp://##.#.#.##

Comment: @madreflection, thanks so much for the correction!